# C# how to write a generic method

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a few `Types` which all have the same "meta data" properties. I want to have a method where I can pass an object, of any `Type`, as an argument to update its meta data.

I can use a `dynamic` argument in the method, something like this:

```
private void UpdateMeta(dynamic obj)
{
    obj.meta1 = DateTime.Now;
    obj.meta2 = "acb";
    obj.meta3 = 123;
    obj.meta4 = "foo";
}

Type1 objtype1 = new Type1();
Type2 objtype2 = new Type2();
Type3 objtype3 = new Type3();

UpdateMeta(objtype1);
UpdateMeta(objtype2);
UpdateMeta(objtype3);
```

But what about type safe generics, what is the exact syntax? Here is what I have so far:

```
private void UpdateMeta<T>(ref T obj)
{
    obj.meta1 = DateTime.Now;
    obj.meta2 = "acb";
    obj.meta3 = 123;
    obj.meta4 = "foo";
}

Type1 objtype1 = new Type1();
Type2 objtype2 = new Type2();
Type3 objtype3 = new Type3();

UpdateMeta<Type1>(objtype1);
UpdateMeta<Type2>(objtype2);
UpdateMeta<Type3>(objtype3);
```

I've looked up examples and documentation but it's mostly about generic classes. I can't seem to get the syntax right

Comment: You need an interface, not generics.

Comment: Your syntax is OK, but the compiler has no way to know that `T` has properties named `meta1`, `meta2`, etc, so the code is not valid.

Comment: btw, unless your types are value types (`struct`), you don't need the `ref` modifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a common base class or interface.then just add a constraint to your generic method:

```
public interface ICommonInterface
{
   // declare your properties here
   // and don't forget to implement this interface in your classes
}

private void UpdateMeta<T>(T obj)
       where T : ICommonInterface
{
    obj.meta1 = DateTime.Now;
    obj.meta2 = "acb";
    obj.meta3 = 123;
    obj.meta4 = "foo";
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, you don't even need to use generics in this case because you are only updating values of some properties.You can just have a method that takes a parameter of type common interface.You can do that changing *dynamic* with a common interface or base class in your first code snippet and you gain the type-safety.

Comment: +1, but the method doesn't even need to be generic; it can just take a ICommonInterface parameter directly

Comment: @ThomasLevesque ofcourse,you're correct.I have updated my answer

Comment: The types / classes are auto generated by Entity Framework. Is it possible to use a partial class to implement an interface?